# bootstrap select 1.13.1 doesn't seem to work even with bootstrap 4 used

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

I tried the simplest code example using bootstrap-select:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Running example of the above code: https://jsfiddle.net/vpjnmatk/6/

The select box doesn't show drop-down when clicked. I am really confused since I think I have already included all the required dependencies. Any idea?

Comment: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem:

[image]

You need Popper.js

Comment: thanks, this works, I will accept as soon as it is available to be accepted. I am just curious, how did you show the error?

Comment: Browser developer tools (F12). Check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools

Answer (score 2):

Include `popper.js` before `bootstrap.min.js`

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following in your `<head>` tags:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```